# What is a relative path like in C?

Tags: c, fopen

I am now using [Visual C++ 2010](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_C%2B%2B#32-bit_and_64-bit_versions) to open a txt file.

```
fp = fopen("E:\\CProg\\Huffman\\Debug\\Huffman.txt","r"); //Right
//Wrong
//fp = fopen(".\\Huffman.txt","r");
//fp = fopen("\\Huffman.txt","r");
//fp = fopen("Huffman.txt","r");
```

In VB.NET, I used to write like this: Application.Startpath & "\". Then how do I make it in C?

Comment: Did you try all of them before asking?

Comment: Then if you couldn't open the file, you probably put it in the wrong folder. If I remember correctly, visual C, runs your application from the root of the project, not from the debug/release folders. Try putting the file there.

Comment: @Shahbaz,You are right.There is **two debug** folders and I had put in the wrong one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relative to what? On "all relevant platforms", if you use a filename that's not absolute it will be resolved relative to the current directory.

The following is for Windows.

If you are writing a console application, the application will start with the current directory set to whatever the command prompt shows. Without further research I can't tell what the initial current directory for a GUI application will be.

If you want your filename to be relative to the Installation directory you'll have to use something like the Win32 function GetModuleFileNameW() and work your way from there (the function gives you the pathname to the exe file; remove the last component to get the directory, and append whatever path you want to append)-

There is no direct way to say "I want this filename to be used relative to the installation directory".

Comment: I was just wondering if I must write the full path every time,since I had put the file at the same directory as the exe.

Comment: @user1518100, no you don't need to (and shouldn't) write the full path.

Comment: For example, if your file is in the same directory as where you run the executable from, writing `fopen("file_name.ext", "r");` is enough. If it's in the parent directory, for example, `fopen("..\\file_name.ext", "r");`. In general, whatever you can write in windows' `cmd` works. The reason is that C doesn't handle the file path, but windows does.